# How can I create a GUI for a text based program?

Tags: c, shell, user-interface

I'm quite in a basic project for now which is recoding a unix shell in C. It is of course intended to work in a tty which means without a GUI. Though I'd like to add an option to use it with a graphical mode. As it's a text based program, when I launch it with Gnome (using alacarte) it launches itself in a Gnome Terminal. What I want to add is a sort of graphical interface like the Gnome Terminal app. Is there a simple way to put a text based program in a sort of frame with graphical elements in it ? I want to get rid of any other application to launch my shell so when I'm in graphical mode (when not using tty) I want my own frame and not another application that launches it.
Can anyone help me ? =)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a GUI using the standard C library.  You can make one with an external library though.

With [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), it is possible to make a GUI, and there is a large community behind the project.  You can find lots of code examples and tutorials on their website.  In addition, you can use OpenCV for lots of other [computer vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) related things.

You could also use [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) to write a GUI for your program.  It is very simple, and easy to use for beginners.  It's more focused on graphics though, and if you want another functionality required by an external library, you might not be able to use GTK+.

Comment: What annoys me is : How can I put my command line based "text field" in a graphical environment ?

Comment: So are you trying to make your own terminal look-alike, with the blinking cursor and all?

Comment: That's quite what I want to do. I coded the shell (redirections, pipes, multi-threading, background and foreground programs, internal programs, external programs and such). So yeah basically now I want to code a terminal emulator GUI.

Comment: I would make the frame first, then have a text area that is set to the color black and fills up the entire frame.  For the blinking cursor, you will have to do a little of your own research on how to make it exactly like the one in the terminal. From there you can implement the shell you have already coded.

Comment: The frame isn't that complicated to do in fact. What causes me trouble is how to create a text area that is dynamically interpreted (and accepts ascii codes like arrows and return) I thought I could use ncurses but that wouldn't lead anywhere since it's used to design ui for command line programs... Quite lost for now.

Comment: The accepting of ASCII codes along with other escape keys would be something to handle in the shell, not the GUI.

Comment: What you are tying to do is wrong and makes no sense in a UNIX environment. If your app is a text based app, then it's a text based app. The user is able to choose the terminal he wants, there's absolutelly no gains in bundling a terminal application that will always be substandard and lack many features the user might expect.

Comment: @niqueco you are wrong.  There are always gains to doing things yourself, even if it is for no easily seen reason. It helps you learn how to program properly and helps you gain more experience.

Comment: It maybe useful as an exercise. It's pointless and misguided as a feature of a serious program. Suppose I want to run your program through a UI menu and instead of finding the terminal I'm used too I find a half-cooked terminal implementation. So, it's more like a bug than a feature.